# Brother HL-2030

Tags: printer

Printer prints perfect Test Page and Text documents, but when it has to print any PDf or image, it prints only the left half of it but twice next to each other with an horizontal empty space between....?
(Printer is recognized and installs automatically. Even though install process seems to hang for ever, but after restart printer seems to be installed, but then works as described above....)
Any Idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Brother has an Debian Linux installer (which will work for elementay OS, by virtue of it being based on Ubuntu which is based on Debian) for the HL-2040. The HL-2040 is the closest driver available and which will most likely work for the HL-2030.

Their [starting page](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hl2040_all) has links for each region supported.

1. Click on the link for the region where the printer is being installed and, on the page that opens, the language the most closely matches that of the user.
2. Browse to the [HL-2040 download page](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hl2040_all) (**Downloads**> **Monochrome Laser** > **HL 2 series**> **HL-2040**).
3. On the HL-2040 Downloads page, select **Linux (deb)** and click the **
   Search** button.
4. On the page that opens, click the **Driver Install Tool** link.
5. Review the EULA and, if you agree, click the **Agree to the EULA and Download** button.

*If you don't agree, this will stop the download process and you can't use the printer driver. If you agree, a download dialog should open.*

6. In the downloads dialog that opens, select **Save** and click the **Okay** button.
7. Now, open an Administrator window in Files (right click on the **Files** icon in the Dock and select 'New Window as Administrator' and enter the password for the admin user on the system (usually the first user account set up during the installation).
8. Click on the the **File System** shortcut (same as alias on OS X) and browse to the Downloads folder *for the user that is currently logged in* (File System/home/userName).
9. Right click on the **Downloads** folder and select **Open In**> **Terminal**.
10. Follow the instructions on in the **How to Install** section on the [Driver Install Tool](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hl2040_all&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625) page starting with **Step 3**.

***Note:*** When the installer prompts you to enter the model name, enter "HL-2030" (without quotes).

11. When the installer finishes (it takes ***many*** minutes so be patient), open the Printers set up dialog (**Applications**> **System Settings**> **Printers**).
12. Locate the model in the pane on the left of the dialog and select it.
13. Verify the status (to the right, above "Location":

    - If it is listed as "Ready", the printer is ready to use.
    - If the status is not, make sure the printer is turned on and connected.

*This completes the process.*

***Note:*** *If the system identifies the driver as missing, try the procedure in [this post](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/how-to-configure-a-missing-printer-driver).*